# How to remove disabled scroll bar in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have a Vue.js application with the router and vuetify enabled. For some reason, there is a disabled scroll bar on the side of the app. How can I remove that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because the content has css style `overflow: scroll`.
Your content is not high enough to scroll so it is looking as disabled.
To not show the disabled scroll, set `overflow: auto` on your container.